# User input validation. Way to do it right in django

Tags: django-templates

I need to validate user email input from the site. Of course there is django.core.validation. However is not it easier to just use jquery validation plugin without sending POST data before all fields are valid? Or it is just better to validate threw views? Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a design decision that you can choose to make. If you need the real-time validation of your fields, then jquery-validation is the way to go.

However, if you want the validation to be done on a postback, you'll be better off using Django's form validation to get the job done.
If you do decide to do the validation on the postback, all of you have to do is use the [EmailField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#emailfield) and django will take care of the rest.

Comment: I'm glad I could be of help. :)